# Kerberos and Kerberos Realms

Tags: kerberos

I am trying to understand Kerberos and Kerberos realms. What I want to know is if you have for example a company with two offices and a headquarters all in different locations with their own local network and with the company servers located at HQ and clients in all offices need access to the servers at HQ would you have a KDC at each location (realms?) or a single KDC at the HQ?

Answer (score 2):

You can have KDC in each segment of you network and then enable cross realm authentication.The details of cross realm authentication can be found at the site given below.

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-kerberos.html.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In a normal scenario you would not set up multiple realms.  Multiple realms designate separate trust domains which may not be necessary.  You may decide to have a separate KDC in each office to reduce latency and this is where physical security concerns may arise a stolen KDC means your entire user database out in the wild.  Microsoft uses RODC http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732801(v=ws.10).aspx, to solve that problem, however as far as I know neither MIT nor Heimdal provide anything similar, in this case you may want to have remote/branch office users in a separate realm and this way if their user database is pilfered it will only be them.  In that case you may want to have a at least one more KDC for the remote realms so that you may be able to quickly enumerate users and change their keys.

There is one more place where cross realm trust is used, when Windows AD and UNIX hosts need to interoperate and UNIX hosts are members of a different realm.